# SAS data joining

Tags: join, sas

Say I have two data sets. 
`Work.one`,`Work.two`.

`Work.one
 X Y
 3 4 
 2 4`

`Work.two
 Z
 10`

Then I submit the following program.

`data work.wh;
  if _n_ = 1 then set Work.two;
  set Work.one;
run;`

The output data set is

`work.wh
 Z  X Y
 10 3 4
 10 2 4`

But actually I want something like

`work.wh
 Z  X Y
 10 3 4
 .  2 4`

Could anyone explain why I get those results and how can I output the data set as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables that are defined in a set/merge/update statement are retained.  If you want it to be set to missing, you need to do that by hand.

```
data work.wh;
  if _n_ = 1 then set Work.two;
  else call missing(z);
  set Work.one;
run;
```